# Why is Jezebel mentioned in Revelation 2: 20?

Tags: revelation

Now I assume that this the same Jezebel from both 1st and 2nd Kings, but what exactly is she representing? Is it just the sexual immorality that the Corrupt Church that John is speaking of? Or is there more to it that I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 4):

Jezebel is a either a symbol of false teaching inside the church or a pseudonym for an actual person, who presented herself as a prophetess while spreading these teachings. This is clear in Rev. 2:20-21

> You tolerate the woman Jez′ebel, who calls herself a prophetess and is
> teaching and beguiling my servants to practice immorality and to eat
> food sacrificed to idols. I gave her time to repent, but she
> refuses to repent of her immorality.

It is not certain that the author has a specific person in mind, but in this verse the interpretation that she represents a union of church and state does not hold up. This "Jezebel" should not be confused with the Whore of Babylon or the "harlot" mentioned in Rev. 17 and 18.  Rather, the author denounces an unknown teacher/s who not only does not *forbid* eating food offered to idols but actively encourages the practice. If the word "immorality" above is translated as "fornication," it could have a similar meaning to some OT uses of term to refer to Israel's "fornication" with idols. However, actual fornication and other immoral sexual acts is a real possibility.

In any case, the author seems to have reference here to the policy enunciated by James  at the so-called Council of Jerusalem in Acts 15:19-29:

> My sentence is, that we trouble not them which from among the
> Gentiles are turned to God: But that we write unto them, that they
> abstain from pollutions of idols, and from fornication, and from
> things strangled, and from blood.

Jezebel thus may represent an extreme "anti-Judaizing" teacher, while the author of Revelation represents a "semi-Judaizing" attitude, in which food offered to idols was a major concern. In other words, she or her faction seem to have intentionally eaten food offered to idols in order to prove the point that "what goes into the mouth does not defile a man." This would not only contradict the policy enunciated by James at the Jerusalem Council, it would also be at odds with the advice of Paul in 1 Cor. 8:

> We are no worse off if we do not eat, and no better off if we do. Only
> take care lest this liberty of yours somehow become a stumbling block
> to the weak. For if any one sees you, a man of knowledge [who
> understands that idols have no power], at table in an idol’s temple,
> might he not be encouraged, if his conscience is weak, to eat 'food
> offered to idols?'... Therefore, if food is a cause of my brother’s falling,
> I will never eat meat, lest I cause my brother to fall.

As mentioned above, followers of Jezebel may also represent that particular type of Christians who, believing that the were no longer "under the Law," felt free to engage in otherwise illicit sex. Paul addressed this problem as well, apparently in order to correct members of the Corinthian church who misunderstood his teaching:

> “All things are lawful for me,” but not all things are helpful... The
> body is not meant for immorality, but for the Lord, and the Lord for
> the body... Do you not know that he who joins himself to a
> prostitute becomes one body with her? For, as it is written, “The two
> shall become one flesh.” But he who is united to the Lord becomes
> one spirit with him. Shun immorality. (1 Cor. 13-18)

**Conclusion: "Jezebel" is a name given to either a real person or a faction within the church. They apparently sought to prove their absolute freedom from the Law of Moses by flaunting their rejection the Council described in Acts 15 regarding food offered to idols, and probably by practicing immoral sexual acts as well. Both of these attitudes were perversions of the idea taught by Paul when he spoke of "the freedom we have in Christ." (Gal. 2:4)**

Answer (score 2):

Literal Jezebel was the daughter of the king of Tyre and the wife of Ahab, the wicked king of Israel in the Old Testament (1 Kings 16:29-31).  She introduced Baal worship into Israel (1 Kings 18) and became a symbol of apostasy and the union of the supposed people of God with pagan worship practices.

Jezebel (Rev 2:20) the harlot (Rev 17, 18) is a most apt symbol/metaphor of Babylon:

- both Jezebels had illicit political and religious relationships,
- both had powerful political ambitions and stopped at nothing to achieve their ends,
- both murdered/martyred God’s people,
- both wore expensive clothes of display,
- both had children,
- both were punished by God and,
- both were killed by those she trusted.  The Jezebel of Thyatira has political ambitions, and the Thyatiran church was reproached for its tolerance of this situation (Rev 2:20).

That is, Jezebel is used as a symbol of the union of church and state where the state enforces false worship.

Comment: +1 small point, Jezebel herself should not be called an apostate. Baal-Melqart was the patron deity of her home city. I suppose she could still be called a 'symbol of apostasy,' but perhaps "opposition to Yahweh worship" would be better?

Comment: @DanFefferman - that is true, but a true apostate is someone who once was a true worshiper and has turned away.  As queen of the norther kingdom of Israel, she lead the once true followers of God astray, thus she became queen of an apostate nation.  Elijah led them back to God.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Dan Fefferman’s answer. I found it very insightful and helpful in understanding. Thank you.

In researching this topic recently, being led by the Holy Spirit, I would also like to add something to be considered, that seems to be overlooked by most commentators on Rev 2:20 that I have read.

Jezebel of Rev 2:20 can be read, first of all, to be

1. **Teaching**
2. AND..also, Persuading them that fornication is not really a sin (something that is notably evident in todays western church and possibly linked to some extent with the feminist movement beginning in the 1960’s)
3. AND..also, Persuading believers with the notion that they can eat food offered to idols (or even perhaps to indulge in activities that are considered sinful by  those of ‘weaker faith’ Eg:alcohol) in order to show how superior ‘their faith’ is in comparison but in doing so, failing to fulfil Jesus’ command to love one another, and rather to refrain from all of those things for the sake of their brother. Eg to ‘love their brother’ or to be ‘their brothers keeper’ .. and through not considering the impact they are having on their weaker brother, they are blind to realising that they have caused their brother to stumble when he also tries to follow their example.

Three points. Not two.

In relation to points 2 and 3.

- This spirit does not love, but destroys Gods people.
- It is love, in ‘name’ only.
- It is individualistic.
- It is selfish.
- It is what we see in much of Christianity today. Sadly.

In particular to this discussion however, it is the first point above, that stood out to me as being overlooked.
Jezebel was **teaching**.

I feel this has been overlooked.
Perhaps the punctuation allows this? or, perhaps the various versions lean towards combining the two facets into one single idea ie “teaching my servants to commit..”?

But not every version interprets it like that. The New King James says “to teach **and** seduce my servants”.

Therefore, I put forth, the possibility, that there are three separate points about Jezebel, in this scripture, not two.

I believe there may be a link in this verse with 1 Timothy 2:12-14 and 1 Corinthians 14:34.

> I do not permit a woman to teach or to exercise authority over a man; rather she is to remain quiet. For Adam was formed first, then Eve; and Adam was not deceived, but the woman was deceived and became a transgressor. 1 Timothy 2:12-14

Since the 1960’s and women’s rights movement, western Christianity has departed from hundreds of years of Christian practice where women were not accorded the right to ‘teach’ men in church according to the scripture. The early church father’s also taught this. (However I discovered that Paul’s’ teaching is not meant to be derogatory to women, it fully allows women to prophesy, just not to *‘judge’* prophecy and also, it fully allows women to teach other women, just not ‘men’). And, is it not possible, that God has good reason that this teaching should have been included in scripture? Even if, we fail to fully understand it, we cannot just pretend it is not there, or even explain it away by saying ‘it was just cultural’.

In the history of Christianity, it has only been in relatively very recent times that women have proliferated as ‘teachers’ of men.

It goes without saying that all of this is far too in depth to go into here, but suffice to say, I am open to understanding. Paul’s teaching, though hard to understand, has to do with Gods divine order, of who is the  **head** of whom? and to whom has God given authority? And for what purpose?  I believe it is one of Paul’s teachings that ‘is hard to understand’ (2 Peter 3:16), because that would explain why it has been so controversial in this last half century.

It is my opinion that it’s quite possible that the world led the way for the church to view the scriptures as being written or at least interpreted by men in an unnecessarily harsh and legalistic light regarding women, (and sadly some Christian men were harsh and legalistic), but many christians went to the other extreme, a very liberal stance that insisted that women must be equal in all functions, whereas God's Word appears to show that women do have a 'different function' from men, yet, and are made 'differently' from men, nevertheless, they are no less loved by God but are equal in value.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't believe Jezebel in Rev 2:20 was the same person or a metaphor to the Queen Jezebel in Kings. It is unthinkable that the Bible is using a person name as a stereotype to something. The Bible had used Babylon, Egypt, Sodom as metaphors but never used the name of a person. In Chapter 12, 17 and 20, there were three other women mentioned, all doesn't give a name. So if this woman of Thyatira was a metaphor, it doesn't have to give her a name, a name that the gentiles in Thyatira couldn't connect to her history.

Furthermore, Queen Jezebel in Kings was not a prophetess, her greatest sins was bringing the Israelites into idol worships, killing the Lord's prophets, instead of adultery. Each letter to the seven churches was written in plain text addressed specific to the spiritual status of each church. If we did not connect Jezebel to Kings, it is still easily understood. On the contrary, it became complicated.

So why would Rev 2:20 mentioned Jezebel? It is because it did have a woman called Jezebel corrupted the church of Thyatira.

What is the significance of these letters to the churches today? The answer may be found when there was a church had similar spiritual downfall as Thyatira, not necessary there was a woman called Jezebel, but anyone who was praised by people with his/her false teaching. However, Jesus was not telling the faithful one to escape, this is what He said:

> Rev 2:24b ‘I will not impose any other burden on you,
>
> Rev 2:25 except to hold on to what you have until I come.

Therefore to understand these letters, the focus is never on Jezebel, but the words of Jesus.